# Why am I unable to detect my Snap Server 18000?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, nas

I have a home server setup made up of old secondhand computers, 2 servers running Windows Server 2003, 1 workstation running Windows 7, a 16 port switch and an ADSL Ethernet modem.

All these connect and talk to each other fine but then I got a "Snap Server 18000" and a "Snap disk 30sa" sata array.

When I turn the Snap on, it boots past the BIOS, runs a kernel, then displays:

> This device cannot be managed via the video/kbd/mouse interface. The video is now disabled. You may access the management functions from your web browser.

Only, none of the other PCs detect it, so no browser can find it!

I have checked all cables, and all LEDs indicate there's a connection. I have installed the windows "iscsi" and the adaptec "Snap Server Manager" on all PCs but still it's not detected.

Answer (score 0):

I have never managed a snap server on the snap server, it is usually always via the web interface.

It is possible that it is not picking up your DHCP server or if this is second hand / from someone elses infrastructure, it could be using hard coded IP settings.

Try pulling out the ethernet cable and putting it back in after a few seconds (usually forces a DHCP refresh) or reset all the settings back to default (take out hard drives first).

Comment: Thanks for the replie!It made me check the DHCP closely.I uninstalled ALL my server rolls & reinstalled the DHCP,(after a battle were the reinstall insisted i had ics running when in services it said it wasnt!).I also had to disconnect the pc from the switch & have both ethernet cables connected to the snap.The snap server manager & ie can detect it,(its invisible everywhere in windows).Now i need to know how to remove a old password before i can access the snap fully,without wipeing everything.Have you any idea how i can do that?Maybe i might get this thing working!!! Lol.